# Using sqlite CLI (Command Line Interface) with dates

Tags: date, sqlite

I am having trouble with sqlite and selecting data using dates. I'm using the sqlite3 CLI (version 3.16.0) on macOS 10.12.5.

I successfully .import data from a csv file where dates have the form `yyyy-MM-dd` (e.g, `2018-07-09` or `2018-12-31` - that is, with leading zero's.) The values are being imported to a TEXT column. The result of `select * ...` from the table shows values without leading zero's e.g., `2018-7-9`.

**The Problem:**

**A:** Using the `sqlite3` command line interface, I run the following query:

`sqlite> select count(*) from reservations where staydate > "2018-1-1";
916`

*This works as expected - there are 916 rows with that data in the table.*

**B:** I then run the same command with another criterion in the WHERE clause:

`sqlite> select count(*) from reservations where staydate > "2018-1-1" and staydate < "2018-12-31";
0`

*This result is incorrect: the query returns zero entries, however examining the data shows that all 916 staydates (from above) are in 2018, so they're being excluded for some reason...*

**My Question:**

How can I make this work in a straightforward way? I have complete control over the format of the data in the .csv file that gets imported, and also table definitions in the database.

What is the simplest combination of csv file format, column definition for the table, and CLI command that will make it work in the obvious way? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your initial import was broken somehow - dates like '2018-07-09' should not stored as an invalid ISO form '2018-7-9'.  You have to solve that problem first.

Comment: Let me guess: there are no staydates in October or November.

Comment: `.import` does not change string values; they leading zeros must be missing in the original file.

Comment: BINGO! you folks gave me the courage to review the *entire* csv file. My supplier changed format :-( changing from mm/dd/yy to m/d/yy part way through. I have tweaked up the formatter to get to the canonical YYYY-MM-DD form, and the selects work as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't mutilate the original question. Post an answer with the resolution and accept it. Accepted answers are how questions are solved on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Done. Thanks for helping me to learn the Stack Overflow way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments above, the CLI .import does not change format for TEXT fields. It turns out that my data files sometimes had leading zeros for months/days, and sometimes not (e.g., 09/07/2017 or 9/7/2017 or even 9/7/17). After realizing that, a simple tweak to my data file format (to a canonical YYYY-MM-DD format) causes everything to work as expected. Thanks to all who responded!